# How to add maxdate in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add maxdate for datepicker and i am using this plugin

```
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
```

**and this is my datepicker code:**

```
.datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    minDate:  new Date(),                                            
    maxDate: +42,
    startDate: indianTimeZoneVal
})
```

But **maxdate** is not working i need current date to next 42 days

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure bootstrap-datepicker has minDate and maxDate.

But for sure it has startDate and endDate instead. Try this,

```
.datepicker({
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true,
 format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
 startDate: new Date(),
 endDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 5))
})
```

Here is the example [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/LcqM7/1162/) for your reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: sure bro - Thank u once again

Comment: is there a way to make one datepicker set the startdate of another? been searching for that

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#element').datepicker({
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true,
format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
startDate:  new Date(),                                            
endDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 42)),
minDate:  new Date(),                                            
maxDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 42))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.datepicker(
    {
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        endDate: '0', 
    }
);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Es6 we can do it by using js

```
currentDate= new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
// convert to substring because datepicker format
//since I am using angular but it's fine with native JS
                <input type="date" id="dateSlot" class="form-control app-inputfield" [min]="currentDate" placeholder="mm/d/year" [(ngModel)]="serviceDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to write the maxdate (endDate) between quotation marks:

```
endDate: '+42d'
```